# SSL certificate on Heroku app not working

Tags: spring, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, zerossl

I recently downloaded an SSL certificate from zeroSSL.com and set it up in my Heroku CLI. Now the website still uses HTTP but it shows that an SSL certificate has been added on heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Heroku shows that the certificate was added, it should be available. Can you successfully browse to your site using HTTPS?

Note that Heroku doesn't redirect from HTTP to HTTPS for you. [They recommend that you do that in application code](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls):

> Redirects need to be performed at the application level as the Heroku router does not provide this functionality. You should code the redirect logic into your application.

That page has several examples for how to redirect using common languages and frameworks. I'm not sure what you're using, but I suggest you start there.